# How to access pg_settings from separate connection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to access the `pg_settings` table from a separate connection belonging to a legacy application.

I know how to identify the connection's `procid` from `pg_stat_activity`, but I am unsure how to get to its `pg_settings` table from here.

I've checked `pg_stat_all_tables`, but that has no reference to any `pg_settings` tables.

`information_schema.tables` has a single row for `pg_settings` with `table_type` set to `VIEW` which indicates to me that I should be looking for a view rather than a table.

How can I access `pg_settings` belonging to a separate connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**`pg_settings`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/view-pg-settings.html) is a view, not a table.

And every session has its own version of it. Per documentation:

> The change only affects the value used by the current session.

The attempt to access it from a *different* connection (session) is futile.

Comment: In other words, it's impossible to access the `pg_settings` view from a different connection using SQL?

Comment: @cpburnz: Each session sees its own version, which reflects session-local settings. I wouldn't know of a way to access another session's version. Internally, the function `pg_show_all_settings()` is called, you could check the Postgres source what it does exactly ...